# Python - 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, django, python-unicode

I'm trying to run a quick Django application that pulls data from Google AdWords and exposes the names of accounts that are managed by an agency. When doing so, I get the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError at /account-hierarchy/
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Here's the snippet:

```
<table class="pretty-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Customer ID</td>
      <td>Client Name</td>
      <td>Can Manage Clients</td>
      <td>Account Currency</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  {% for account in managed_accounts %}
    <tr>
      {% for field in account %}
        <td>{{ field }}</td>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

where the call to `{{ field }}` is the problematic line.

I have already added

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

to the template I am rendering, but it still fails, so I believe the problem is not on the HTML template, but rather on the Python/Django engine.

Any ideas how I can fix it?

Here's the View code that renders the template:

```
def account_hierarchy(request):
manager_ids = settings.MANAGER_IDS
managed_accounts = []
for manager_id in manager_ids:
    managed_accounts.extend(adwords_utils.getManagedAccounts(manager_id))
return render_to_response('simple-table.html', {"managed_accounts": managed_accounts})
```

**UPDATED Question**

- Python Version: 2.7.6
- Models.py is currently empty

What's also curious is that if I remove this:

```
{% for field in account %}
    <td>{{ field }}</td>
  {% endfor %}
```

and I just print out the main array:

```
{{ managed_accounts }}
```

it works just fine. Not sure what's going on.

Curious fact #2: As I managed to output the full array, I checked for character 'é' and I didn't find it on the final output. Not sure where it was coming from.

Comment: Perhaps define the `__unicode__` method in your `models.py` would work

Comment: Could you also include some related codes in your `models.py`?

Comment: I am not using any models yet. So models.py is empty.

Comment: Then you would probably need to encode some of the data in `managed_accounts`

Answer (score 4):

The problem is likely that, in some place in your code, you accidentally defined a data structure to be a Python byte string, when you should have made it a Python Unicode string. This leads Django and Python to convert from Django's Unicode string to your byte string, in a default way, using the ASCII codec.

The error message gives some clues:

- The error is perhaps occurring when you call `account_hierarchy()`
- The phrase `character u'\xe9' in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)` means that Python is trying to convert Unicode character 'é' (U+00E9) into an ASCII value from 0..127.  Look in your data for an 'é'. Which field is it in?
- The phrase `'ascii' codec` means the conversion is likely inadvertent. If you intend to use UTF-8, you wouldn't have called the ASCII codec intentionally. But when you cause a conversion but don't specify a codec, Python uses ASCII.
- The word `encode` means conversion from Unicode to byte-oriented encoding.  You have read [Python's *Unicode HOWTO* article](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) a couple of times, haven't you?

Function [render_to_response()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.render_to_response) uses settings [DEFAULT_CHARSET](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-DEFAULT_CHARSET) and DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE). They should default to 'utf-8' and 'text/html', which should be appropriate for generating a UTF-8 encoded HTML page, but check.

I like the suggestion that you check your `models.py` to be sure that your models are defined in terms of Unicode data types, not byte string data types. *Update*: you say models.py is empty, so that won't be much help.

Character handling, and Unicode vs byte strings, are handled differently in Python 2 and Python 3. Which version of Python are you using? *Update*: Python 2.7.6, thanks. The *Unicode HOWTO* I linked to above is for Python 2.7.x.

If you make sure your code handles strings as Unicode throughout, unless you really want a byte string, that will likely fix this problem.

*Update*: Consider modifying your template to give you debugging information. Try something like these expressions, to see what's really in `managed_accounts`:

```
</thead>
<tr><td>managed_accounts is: {{ repr(managed_accounts) }}</tr></td>
{% for account in managed_accounts %}
  <tr>
  {% for field in account %}
    <td>{{ type(field) }}, {{ repr(field) }}</td>
  {% endfor %}
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

[*Updated* in response to multiple updates from original poster.]

Comment: Nice and detailed answer!

Answer (score 0):

**your problem is same with mine,just encode question, you can add bellow code in your views.py of django project:**

```
 1. #coding=utf-8  
 2. import sys
 3. reload(sys)
 4. sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

my problem:
Error during template rendering
In template D:\PythonProjects\DjangoProject\guest\sign\templates\sign\guest_manage.html, error at line 72
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcfSz.png)

Answer (score 0):

**This is issue belongs to jinja2 templating and will be resolve by setting encoding as utf-8 as default encoding.**

`sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')`